# Exercise about annihilators and linear functionals from Halmos

Tags: linear-algebra, duality-theorems

I am currently reading "Finite dimensional vectors spaces" by Halmos. Could anyone check if my proof of a specific exercise (page 27 exercise 5) is rigorous enough and correct? The topics are annihilator and linear functionals.

> Prove that if $m < n$, and if $y_{1}, \dots, y_{m}$ are linear functionals on an n-dimensional vector space $\mathbb{V}$, then there exists a non-zero vector $x$ in $\mathbb{V}$ such that $y_{j}(x) = 0$ for $j = 1, \dots, m$. What does this result say about the solutions of linear equations?

The basic idea here is to use the isomorphism between $\mathbb{V}$ and $\mathbb{V}''$. If $\mathbb{V}$ is a finite-dimensional vector space, then corresponding to every linear functional $z_{0}$ on $\mathbb{V}'$ there is a vector $x_{0}$ in $\mathbb{V}$ such that $z_{0}(y) = y(x_{0})$ for every y in $\mathbb{V}'$. Now we define $S := span\{y_{1}, \dots, y_{m}\} \subset \mathbb{V}'$. $S$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{V}'$. Since $y_{1}, \dots, y_{m}$ are not necessarily linearly independent it follows that $\dim S \leq m < n = \dim \mathbb{V}'$. We describe the annihilator of $S$ with $S^0$ which is a $n-m$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{V}''$. Since $m < n$ we know that $S^0$ has at least dimension 1 and this means that $S^0$ contains at least one linear functional which isn't the 0-functional. Using the isomorphism between $\mathbb{V}$ and $\mathbb{V}''$ we pick a vector $z_{0} \in \mathbb{V}''$. The theorem above ensures that there exists a vector $x_{0}$ such that $z_{0}(y) = y(x_{0})$ for every $y \in \mathbb{V}'$. From this it follows that there exists a vector $x_{0}$ such that $z_{0}(y) = y_{j}(x_{0})$ for $j = 1, \dots, m$. Since a linear functional is always surjective we can deduce that $z_{0}(y) = y_{j}(x_{0}) = 0$ for $j = 1, \dots, m$. We can make a more specific statement in $x_{0} \in \cap_{j=1}^m \ker y_{j}$.

The result tells us that given $m$ linear equations with the right side of the equations being 0, we can find a non-trivial solution.

Also the next exercise is quite similar but I am not sure how to start it. Maybe someone has a hint for me?

> Suppose that $m < n$, and that $y_{1}, \dots, y_{m}$ are linear functionals on an n-dimensional vector space $\mathbb{V}$. Under what conditions on the scalars $\alpha_{1}, \dots, \alpha_{m}$ is it true that there exists a vector $x$ in $\mathbb{V}$ such that $y_{j}(x) = \alpha_{j}$ for $j = 1, \dots, m$. What does this result say about the solutions of linear equations?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your reasoning for the first appears ok to me. As for the 2nd, if I am understand things here correctly, in that case, instead of the system being homogeneous (output is 0 vector), it is asking about inhomogeneous systems (output isn't 0 vector). In that case, I suspect that the answer has to do w/ rank and/or nullity of the corresponding matrix (this in turn has to do w/ subspace spanned by the $y_j$'s and the quotient of the entire space by that space).

Comment: Ok I got an idea but I don't know if I'm on the right track. If one vector of $y_{1}, \dots, y_{m}$ is linearly dependent then I define dim span {$y_{1}, \dots, y_{m}$} := m - 1 and we can say that m - 1 < m < n. Now lets say that the linear dependent vector is $y_{m}$ then we can write $y_{m}(0) = \alpha_{m}$. Now if $\alpha_{m} \neq 0$ then we have no solution (so no $x$).

Comment: I think that's right, that was more or less my train of thought here too.

Comment: Ok Thanks mate :D

Comment: [Link2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/od5fcc1e2dex2uo/halmos4.pdf?dl=0) Ok here ist way I wrote it up if you are interested. Thanks for the help again.